# Mean and Variance of dot product of 2 random vectors?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, stochastic-processes

x and y are two vectors of dimension k.
Assume that the components of x and y are independent random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. What would be the mean and variance of their dot product, x · y ?

Comment: what are the covariances among the elements of $x$ and similarly among the elements of $y$?

Comment: @gunes The covariances are 0 based on the assumption that all elements are independent random variables.

Comment: Are x and y also independent?

Answer (score 2):

If everything is mutually independent, assuming $\sigma^2$ is the common variance (in your case it's $1$), and RVs have zero mean RVs as stated in the OP:

$$\operatorname{var}\left(\sum x_iy_i\right)=k\operatorname{var}(x_1y_1)=kE[x_1^2]E[y_1^2]=k\sigma^4$$

$$E\left[\sum x_iy_i\right]=kE[x_1y_1]=0$$